# in date_sub function while using a interval can we use an interval of month and day combined?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I need to select database for the past month is this the correct way?

```
$month1=mysql_query("select * from users where date_sub(concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00'), interval 1 month day(curdate()) day) < start and start < date_sub(concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00'), interval day(curdate()) day)");
```

Is this field correct in particular: `date_sub(concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00'), interval 1 month day(curdate()) day)`

Is there any best short alternative to simply select a table of **JUST the previous month** from the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
   WHERE YEAR(`start`) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
      AND MONTH(`start`) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

EDIT: correction for the year condition.

Comment: This is actually static dude...but I will be needing a dynamic code which has to select the previous month DB. so if I go the next month still its gonna select the month of 6 but i would be needing month of 7

Comment: No, the year is also dynamic. See **YEAR(\`start\`) = YEAR(NOW())**

Comment: No what I was asking was like can't it run with out the year part?

Comment: Actually, that year part has an error :) It won't do the trick for the last month of the year. It's now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to concatenate '00:00:00'
- You are subtracting 1 month plus some number of days, rather than just 1 month. You can only pass 1 parameter to the interval.

Go with

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

The `day()` function actually gives you the day of the month, so you would use this if you wanted to get all records from the start of the month

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) day);
```

Today is the 15th July, so this would get all records from the 1st to 15th

Comment: i need: _1/6/2012 to 31/6/2102_   This way i.e. the whole DB of **just the past month**

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE start > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

If you need it between 2 exact dates :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE start BETWEEN  '2012-06-01' AND '2012-06-31'
```

For none static requests :

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE start > DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(
                            DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH
                        )),INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
AND start <= DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(
                          DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH
                      )),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Make sure you have an index on `start`.

Comment: Dude this gives from _14/6/2012 to present day_ but i need: _1/6/2012 to 31/6/2102_

Comment: This is actually static dude...but I will be needing a dynamic code which has to select the previous month DB. so if I go the next month still its gonna select the month of 6 but i would be needing month of 7

Comment: My last edit should fix this. It's pretty fast on `200K` rows takes `0.0006` secondes.